# Premiere Pro - Unwanted Letterboxing in HD 1080p Video

Tags: video, premiere, editing, software, camera

After editing a video in Premiere Pro CC 2015 and then exporting it, a 1080p video becomes letter-boxed on the left and right sides. I have double checked all the settings, and for some reason it continues to letter box.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=leOeuSAEK5U) is an example video to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

That can happen, when you use different Pixel aspect Ratio. Use Match Sequence Settings and use Pixel aspect Ratio in your sequence same with footage.